# Java Script, Count down, Link Removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, hyperlink

Can anyone please help me with below code. It's a count down, it work brilliant on my website but I don't want it to link back to tick counter website. Is there any way I can stop it linking back to any other website?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

```
<div class="tcw" data-id="Countdown-38213" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%">
<a href="//www.tickcounter.com/countdown/38213/flash-sale" title="Flash Sale">Flash Sale</a>
<a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">Countdown</a>
</div>
<style>
.tcw:after { 
  content: ""; 
  display: block; 
  margin-top: 25%; 
}
</style>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) { 
  var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id; 
  js.src = "//www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js"; 
  pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs); 
}
(document, "script", "tickcounter-sdk"));
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the link with out break the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095685/how-do-i-remove-the-link-with-out-break-the-code)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not so ethical but if that's what you want, remove the following line.

```
<a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">Countdown</a>
```

**EDIT:**

So, I messed around with it on JSFiddle and I came up with this. 
Try using jQuery to add css on with delay.

```
$('.counter-wrapper')
  .delay(800)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none'); 
    next(); 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for our reply, I tried that but as soon as I'm making any changes to the code nothing shows up in the browser :(

Comment: @sapna I edited my answer giving you a css solution. As this DOM object is required, you can hide it using CSS.

Comment: thank you, this just solved my issue, although I added pointer-event:none to the div wrap around iframe.