# How do I remove the link with out break the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I have this count down code it works just fine, the only problem is it's linking back to tickcounter website. I want to remove that link without breaking the code but it seems impossible, as soon as I'm making any changes nothing shows up in the browser. I can only add inline CSS as I only have access to magento cms. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

```js
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js";
  pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
}(document, "script", "tickcounter-sdk"));
```

```css
.tcw:after { content: ""; display: block; margin-top: 25%; }
```

```html
<div class="tcw" data-id="Countdown-38455" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%">
<a href="//www.tickcounter.com/countdown/38455/flash-sale" title="FLASH SALE">FLASH SALE</a>
<a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">Countdown</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaking the code'? If you add a bunch of line breaks to make this more readable, you're more likely to get more help.

Comment: First, format your code. Second, please explain expected behavior.

Comment: Possibly share a link with the code in use?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back to me sorry I'm just a bit new to this website. So going back to the question. Everytime I try to add any code to the iframe it doesn't load the count down, nothing shows up in the browser about the count down, even though you can clearly see javascript loading.

Comment: so when I say breaking I mean the count down don't show up, it's just a blank space, despite javascript loading

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No.

It's not just linking but loading a javascript file directly from ticketcounter website. CSS is not a programming language like JS, inline-css won't get you work done.

If you want to remove that link, you need to include related javascript code to your web page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes can remove that link and put your js. 
Follow below steps.

1. open http://www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js and copy the render js to your own js file.
2. link your js file as below.

> js.src = "//www.yourwebsite.com/js/loader.js";